# Python Raspi: Loop Bomb beeping

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to have a sound beeping over and over again, 15 minutes long.

The interval should always get shorter, so that in the end it is beeping constantly. It should be like a ticking bomb. Do you know what I mean?

The question is, how do I know how long to wait in every iteration of the loop?

I have a code like this in the loop:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(.5)
    GPIO.output(buzzPin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.5)
    GPIO.output(buzzPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    # wait here with changing interval
```

But now I need to wait at the end. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: this is something you would have to calibrate yourself to see what sounds the better to you.

Comment: I'd do something like `time.sleep(delay); delay *= 0.99`

Comment: @PM2Ring this is not guaranteed to produce an almost uniform sound towards the end though.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: True, it was just a suggestion, not a proper answer (which is why it's in a comment :) ). And I don't have a Raspberry Pi to test it on.

Comment: You could use a geometric sum to calculate the delay based on some count variable `i`. For instance, `time.sleep(a*(r**i))` where `r = 0.5`, `a = 15*60*(1-r)`, and `i += 1` within the loop. Or use any other equation to calculate some gradually decreasing delay like `a/i`.

Comment: Do you want your loop to end?